# How to test Actors values with a factory as receiver

Tags: scala, akka

Let say I have an actor called TestedActor wich is able to save an Int value and send it back as follow:

```
class TestedActor extends Actor {
  override def receive = receive(0)

  def receive(number: Int): Receive = {
    case new_number: Int => context.become(receive(new_number))
    case ("get", ref: ActorRef) => ref ! number
  }
}
```

In my test, I would like to be able to get this Integer and test it.

So i've been thinking about creating something like:

```
class ActorsSpecs extends FlatSpec with Matchers {

  case class TestingPositive(testedActor: ActorRef) extends Actor {
    override def receive = {
      case number: Int => checkNumber(number)
      case "get" => testedActor ! ("get", self)
    }

    def checkNumber(number: Int) = {
      number should be > 0
    }
  }

  implicit val system = ActorSystem("akka-stream")
  implicit val flowMaterializer = ActorMaterializer()

  val testedActor = system.actorOf(Props[TestedActor], name = "testedActor")
  val testingActor = system.actorOf(Props(new TestingPositive(testedActor)), name = "testingActor")

  testingActor ! "get"
}
```

This way, i'm able to create this TestingPositive actor, to get the number in the TestedActor and test it in checkNumber.

It seems to be working well, my problem is :

When the test fail, it raise an exception in the actor thread, I can see what went wrong in the console, but it is still saying that all my tests succeeded. Because (I think) the main thread is not aware of this failure.

Does someone knows an easier way than all of this TestingActor stuff?

Or any solution to tell the main thread that it failed?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at using `TestKit` [docs here](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/testing.html#Asynchronous_Integration_Testing_with_TestKit).  You can write a much simpler test for your actor.  See how you like this test:

```
import akka.actor.{Props, ActorSystem}
import akka.testkit.{TestProbe, TestKit}

import org.scalatest.{BeforeAndAfterAll, FlatSpecLike, ShouldMatchers}

class ActorSpecs extends TestKit(ActorSystem("TestSystem"))
  with FlatSpecLike
  with ShouldMatchers
  with BeforeAndAfterAll {

  override def afterAll = {
    TestKit.shutdownActorSystem(system)
  }

  def fixtures = new {
    val caller = TestProbe()
    val actorUnderTest = system.actorOf(Props[TestedActor], name = "testedActor")
  }

  "The TestedActor" should "pass a good test" in {
    val f = fixtures; import f._

    caller.send(actorUnderTest, 42)
    caller.send(actorUnderTest, ("get", caller.ref))
    caller.expectMsg(42)
  }

  "The TestedActor" should "fail a bad test" in {
    val f = fixtures; import f._

    caller.send(actorUnderTest, 42)
    caller.send(actorUnderTest, ("get", caller.ref))
    caller.expectMsg("this won't work")
  }
}
```

Also, you should know about `sender`.  While your `get` certainly works, a cleaner approach might be to reply to the sending actor:

```
def receive(number: Int): Receive = {
  case new_number: Int => context.become(receive(new_number))
  case "get" => sender ! number
}
```

And the test becomes:

```
"The TestedActor" should "pass a good test" in {
  val f = fixtures; import f._

  caller.send(actorUnderTest, 42)
  caller.send(actorUnderTest, "get")
  caller.expectMsg(42)
}
```

And finally, I'll shamelessly plug [my recent blog post](http://proseand.co.nz/2015/05/17/akka-honeymoon/) about maintaining an akka code base with my team. I feel morally obligated to give a new hAkker an opportunity to read it. :)

Comment: Thank you it's working well! I didn't know for the "sender" thing ! I'll read your blog ;)